# Prove a formula is not a logical consequence of KB

Tags: logic

To prove that a formula A is a logical consequence of KB, we could prove by using [resolution that] negation of A [not(A)] and KB lead to inconsistency.

Now if it is assumed that A is not a consequence of KB, is it the same as claiming

```
KB union not(A) is consistent
```

thus there must be an interpretation that satisfies it?

What about the case where A is a contradiction like p and not(p) or a tautology like p or not(p)?

Grateful for any help

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting.

Comment: What is KB? ${}$

Comment: @Wojowu: How do you write a comment with less than 15 characters?

Comment: @Wojowu: probably "knowledge base". And how **do** you write a comment with less than 15 characters?

Comment: @Wojowu, yes you are correct, KB is the knowledgebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *contradiction* $p \land \lnot p$ is always *false*; thus, it is not *satisfiable*.

The negation of a contradiction is always *true*, i.e. is a *tautology*.

We have that $p \land \lnot p$ is not consequence of $KB$.

To show it, consider:

> $KB \cup \{ \lnot (p \land \lnot p) \}$.

Assuming that $KB$ is *satisfiable*, due to the fact that $\lnot (p \land \lnot p)$ is a tautology, every interpretation satisfying $KB$ will also satisfy $KB \cup \{ \lnot (p \land \lnot p) \}$.

This means that we cannot derive a contradiction from it and this, by resolution, shows that $p \land \lnot p$ is not consequence of $KB$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the case when A is not a tautology or contradiction? Could we use  KB union not(A) is consistent  to show if A is not a consequence

Comment: @AllenM.D - Yes; if $KB ∪ \{ ¬A \}$ is consistent, i.e. *satisfiable*, then $A$ is **not** a logical consequence of $KB$.