# Consistency of a Knowledge base (resolution)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

To prove Q is a logical consequence of a knowledge base KB, it is possible to add not(Q) to KB and perform resolution, and reach an empty clause.

But how is it possible to show Q is not a consequence of KB by using resolution? For example, not being able to reach an empty clause under which circumstances can be a proof that Q does not follow?

I understand that one method to prove Q is not a consequence of KB is to assign truth values to each clause that make everything consistent. But that is not my focus, I am interested to know reaching what conditions while performing resolution can show me Q does not follow from KB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [prove-a-formula-is-not-a-logical-consequence-of-kb](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669013/prove-a-formula-is-not-a-logical-consequence-of-kb).

Comment: [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) for porpositional logic is "sound and complete algorithm for deciding the satisfiability of a propositional formula, and, by extension, the validity of a sentence under a set of axioms." Thus, if applying the proof procedure until you cannot proceed any more you have not produced the empty clause, this means that the set of formulae is *satisfiabble*. But this set is made of the premises and the negation of the conclusion; thus, this implies that the conclusion is **not** consequence of the premises.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  thanks for your feedback. I guess what I am wondering about is this: how do I know I can't proceed anymore because I am incorrect or missing a step or is it because there is actually no resolution.... Are there any indicators?

Comment: See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) : "If the empty clause cannot be derived, **and the resolution rule cannot be applied to derive any more new clauses**, the conjecture is not a theorem of the original knowledge base."